# Creating instance of a class by parsing the values of attributes from a csv (or maybe some other way?)

Tags: java, json, string, csv

I have a Myclass with 11 "normal" String attributes, and 12th is a list of type OtherClass - and this class has 2 attributes, 1 string and 1 int

```
 public class MyClass extends BaseEntity
    private String string1;
    private String string2;
    // ...
    private String string11;
    private List<OtherClass> otherClasslist = new ArrayList<OtherClass>();
    getters setters
```

that's the first class, and the second one

```
public class OtherClass extends BaseEntity
private String foo;
private int bar;
//getters setters
```

And I have a CSV file with values of attributes of one instance, and the names of the columns in the first row. For example:

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;foo1;bar1;foo2;bar2

so;me;thi;ng;and;so;on;and;so;forth;and;on;foo;10
so;me;thi;ng;and;so;on;and;so;forth;and;on;foo;10 (different values)
```

and a few lines like this

I have a repository for the main class - and simply for each line to create a new instance of class MyClass and save it to the repository. What is the best angle to aproach it? Should I somehow parse the CSV so I have a list of Strings which has the values of attributes in it, and somehow go from there? Also if it is an option at all, I have a method which saves the object into repo if I have it in JSON, is CSV>JSON conversion doable? If the list (12th attribute) is an issue you can ignore it, just give me some suggestion for a workable model of a solution.

Comment: I strongly recommend you using `String[]` instead of  11 `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not parse CSV yourself, just as you shouldn't write JSON from scratch. There are established libraries for both.

CSV: [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

JSON: [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

Unserialize from OpenCSV to your custom class, then use a JSON framework to serialize to JSON. If you have a large batch of such conversions to do, you might consider using a batch framework like [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/).

Theoretically, a direct conversion from CSV to JSON is possible, as all JSON frameworks can be used programmatically, but I would not encourage this: it mingles input and output together. I prefer having a canonical representation of your data in your own code and mapping that to input and output.